# Initializing FB session on client using javascript sdk and long lived token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am a bit confused about the implementation of access token in FB graph api.

According to the docs I can pass the access token to client and initialize the session using this access token

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

So if I have a long lived access token on server side and pass it to the javascript sdk on client side...is it possible to make graph api calls from client? How?

Answer (score 1):

Facebooks's JS SDK `.api()` method always accepts a parameter called `access_token`, that can be a User access_token or a Page access_token depending on the calls you are making. See the following example using Angular's SDK:

Get a 
`this.fb.api(pageId + '?fields=picture,fan_count,name', 'get', { 'access_token': <USER_ACCESS_TOKEN> })`

Where `<USER_ACCESS_TOKEN>` is given to you by your backend without exposing your API secret ever. So, in summary.

See [Generating Long-Lived User Tokens from Server-Side Long-Lived Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension#long-via-code) for more info.